# How to show my Firefox icon on my panel (GNOME)?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3, gui

I am new to Linux (I've been studying it for just about few days, and I have just installed Fedora workstation on my desktop.), and I downloaded Firefox Developer Edition for just testing it. I can just do extracting tar.bz file, and opening 'firefox' file in the extracted folder. I want to show it on the panel of GNOME, how can I do it? Does Linux have the folder which has the same concepts as the folder called 'Program Files' in MS Windows? What is process of showing it on the panel?

Comment: I do not use Gnome or Fedora but I would expect a "right mouse click" would start to put you in the right direction to adding / editing panels and desktop features.

Answer (score 0):

To create any shortcut you just need to create a .desktop file for the software as shown below:

```
[Desktop Entry] 

    Version=1.0 
    Type=Application 
    Terminal=false 
    Icon[en_CA]=gnome-panel-launcher Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new 

    Name[en_CA]=Create Desktop Shortcut Name=Create Desktop Shortcut Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange communities are different than other sites. Please take the [Tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works. Please read the Help Center article [How do I write a good answer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Then edit your answer to make it a complete solution to the question. Perhaps rewrite the file contents to launch an actual program, and then say where to save this file.